# Keeping time and time difference in realtime in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to get the elapsed time from the order time, but I’m getting a warning
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

What’s should be the correct approach in Vue?

Current Time: 2018-06-18T09:12:21+08:00
Order Number: 1
Order Time: 2018-06-16 Saturday 23:06:92 Elasped Time:
Item    Size    Quantity    Price   Subtotal
Test Pizza  16  1   100 100.00

Here’s what I’ve tried:

```
    <tbody>
                    <div class="class order-number">
                        <strong><em>Order Number: {{ getOrders.indexOf(orders)+1 }}</em></strong>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">X</button>
                        <!-- <div>{{ getOrders[getOrders.indexOf(orders)] }}</div> -->
                        <div>Order Time: {{ formatOrderTime(getOrders, orders) }}  <em>Elasped Time: </em> 
<span :style="sytleState">{{ elaspedTime(getOrders, orders) }}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div></div>
                    <tr v-for="(orderItems, index) in orders['.value']" :key='index'>
                        <td>{{ orderItems.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ orderItems.size }}</td>
                        <td>{{ orderItems.quantity }}</td>
                        <td>{{ orderItems.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ (orderItems.quantity*orderItems.price).toFixed(2) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

---

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'numberOfOrders',
            'getMenuItems',
            'getOrders'
        ]),
},
methods: {    
                getOrderTime(getOrders, orders) {
                this.orderTime = getOrders[getOrders.indexOf(orders)]['.value'][0]['orderTime']
                return this.orderTime
            },
            formatOrderTime(getOrders, orders) {
                return moment(getOrders[getOrders.indexOf(orders)]['.value'][0]['orderTime']).format("YYYY-MM-DD dddd HH:MM:SS ") 
            },
            elaspedTime(getOrders, orders) {
                    this.timeElapsed = moment(this.now).diff(getOrders[getOrders.indexOf(orders)]['.value'][0]['orderTime'])
                    return moment.duration(this.timeElapsed).minutes()
            },
```

Any help appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Are `getOrderTime` and `elapsedTime` methods meant to be getters? They should be pure. They should not modify state, especially if you're calling them from within the template (i.e. during the render) because it will trigger another render (hence the warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using computed, filters didn't quite work out.

```
               <div>Order Time: {{ moment(getOrderTime[index]).format() }}  <br>
                    <em>Elasped Time: </em> 
                    <span :style="sytleState">
                        {{ elaspedTime[index].days }} days
                        {{ elaspedTime[index].hours }} hrs
                        {{ elaspedTime[index].minutes }} min
                        {{ elaspedTime[index].seconds }} sec
                    </span>
                </div>




computed: {
        getOrderTime() {
            return this.getOrders.map(function(orders) {
                return orders['.value'][0]['orderTime']
            }) 
        },
        elaspedTime() {
            let now = this.now
            return this.getOrders.map(function(orders) {
                let value = now - orders['.value'][0]['orderTime']
                return { 
                    days: moment.duration(value).days(), 
                    hours: moment.duration(value).hours(), 
                    minutes: moment.duration(value).minutes(), 
                    seconds: moment.duration(value).seconds() 
                    }
            }) 
        },
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

While what is written in the comments above is true (start using getters or computed properties), I find this the absolute easiest way dealing with this, since you already use moment - using Vue filter!

```
Vue.filter('moment-ago', function (date) {
   return moment(date).fromNow()
})
```

And then in the template you can just use it like:

```
<div class="ago">{{ yourVariable | moment-ago }}</div>
```

There is no need to calculate time difference, nor write methods for it :)

Good luck!

Comment: First of all, thanks for the responses.
@Andrey Firstly, to get the orderTime I did the following, which does not work as the initial value for orderTime = 0. 
How should the orderTime value from the v-for be passed to data?


   <div>Order Time: {{ orderTime | formatOrderTime }}


    filters: {
        formatOrderTime(getOrders, orders) {
            return moment(getOrders[getOrders.indexOf(orders)]['.value'][0] 
   ['orderTime']).format("YYYY-MM-DD dddd HH:MM:SS ") 
        },

Comment: You should do it vice versa - first get what you want, and THEN call the moment function to calculate time. Now you try to put the logic into the filter itself, and the filter doesn't know about any orders :)